# Problem on dragging items on Jquery UI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI sortable to allow user to drag and drop between two lists and then order the items, but I have an error where when selecting from the first list, the content selected it's not the entire `div`, just the content on behind the mouse cursor.

[image]

Following this, many errors occurs, like I'm not able to order, to move back to the first list and everything can't be undone.

Here's the view code:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Games.AvailableGamesStats.GameAchievements.Where(f => f.SectionID == null))
    {
        <div class="connectedSortable" id="achievements" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; z-index:1; cursor:move; height:60px">
            <img src="@item.Icon" style="float:left" />
            <b>@item.DisplayName</b><br />
            <i>@item.Description</i>
            @if (item.Difficulty != null)
            {
                <img src="@item.Difficulty.DifficultyImage" style="float:right; width:32px" />
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card" style="height:100%; z-index:0">
        <div class="card-header text-center" contenteditable="true">Name</div>
        <div class="card-body connectedSortable" id="chievo">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery...

```
    $(function () {
    $("#chievo, #achievements").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

The first div items that I'm trying to move, are a collection of image, title and description, but when I try to move, only one item moves, and can't order or undo anything.

Comment: I suspect you need to properly define the items. See: https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

Comment: You must be missing closing tag somewhere check your rendered html

Comment: the html is correct, but when i paste here, it's remove the div close tag, but it's correct here.

Comment: @Twisty it worked! you've saved me, aswer the question, and i'll mark it ;)